# Excel Webservice Function Yahoo Finance

Tags: excel, api, yahoo, finance, stockquotes

I have the following problem: I use the yahoo finance API with excel to pull stock quotes. This usually works. The function looks e.g. like this:

=NUMBERVALUE(WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT&f=l1"))

However, after using this successfully it suddenly stopped working and just returns #VALUE. I haven't found an answer anywhere. I have un- and reinstalled Excel and I even have un- and reinstalled Windows 8.1. It just doesn't work anymore.

I use a MacBook Pro, with Parallels, where I installed Windows 8.1. on which I run office (I hate MS Office for Mac). Maybe this has sumething to do with the problem? I don't know. Maybe some permissions are blocked or so. Do you have an answer? Furthermore, the link only works in 1 specific condition...

- Firefox (Mac): Link works
- Safari (Mac): Link does not work
- Firefox (Windows): Link does not work
- Internet Explorer (Windows): Link does not work

Krd
Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the API now requires an extra parameter `&e=.csv`. Add it to the end of your URL and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks arturhoo, but that doesn't solve the problem for me. I noticed also the following:

When I open the link, e.g.: 
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT&f=l1
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=nl1r&e=.csv

Comment: It seems to be back to normal now.

Comment: Yes indeed. Seems that it was just a problem born by Yahoo Servers or so.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked for me. 
The original string I was using in an Excel was

```
=NUMBERVALUE(WEBSERVICE("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&C22&"&f=l1"))
```

Where `C22` was the cell where the stock ticker was.
I updated link part before `finance.yahoo.com` so now it looks like

```
=NUMBERVALUE(WEBSERVICE("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="&C22&"&f=l1"))
```